# how to convert a datetime string back to datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I am storing a `datetime` string in a database. Now I face a problem. When I fetch the string from the database, I need to convert it back to a `datetime` object...

Any easy way to do that?

The string of datetime looks like:

```
2010-11-13 10:33:54.227806
```

Comment: duplicate of [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/10197418)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want datetime.strptime(date_string, format).

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime("2010-11-13 10:33:54.227806", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

For details on the format string, see http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 7):

I sugggest you install [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) with `pip install python-dateutil`:

```
from dateutil import parser
d = parser.parse(yourstring)
```

This library gets a `datetime` object from your date string in a 'smart' way...

Comment: Depends on your definition of smart. It tries to guess the format of your date string, and its guess might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
# time tuple to datetime object
    time_tuple = (2008, 11, 12, 13, 51, 18, 2, 317, 0)
    dt_obj = datetime(*time_tuple[0:6])
    print repr(dt_obj)

# date string to datetime object
    date_str = "2008-11-10 17:53:59"
    dt_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    print repr(dt_obj)

# timestamp to datetime object in local time
    timestamp = 1226527167.595983
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    print repr(dt_obj)
```